# jsonexport not saving proper xls file on windows

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, express

```
  var arrayData = [{"Email":"Email","P1":"TEST1","P2":"P2"}
                   {"Email":"Email","TEST1":"TEST1","TEST2":"TEST2"}];//JSON DATA

  var jsonexport = require('jsonexport');
  var options = { rowDelimiter:'\t'};

  jsonexport(arrayData,options,function(err, xlsfile){
      if(err) return console.log("error while writing xls file "+err);
      var pathToSave = '/Desktop/test.xls';
      fs.writeFileSync(pathToSave, xlsfile, 'binary');
      cb(null,pathToSave)
  });
```

Above code saving `.xls` file properly on Linux, but on Windows when we open file it showing error as file format and file extension don't match. File could be corrupted or unsafe.

Comment: `In above code saving xls file properly `, you mean in linux?

Comment: yes in linux it is opening through LibreOffice but when we try with MS office in Windows it is showing above error while opening file

Comment: You are using `Excel` to open that?

Comment: On `Windows`, the `pathToSave` might not exists. You can try giving relative paths so that it works on all the platforms

Comment: The problem is in windows while opening through  Excel

Comment: File saving properly but it is not opening and the same file opening in Linux Machine